# Count cells that doesn't end with 1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=(Countifs(B:B;”*”;F:F;”<>*1”))
```

Why doesn't this work?

I want to count all the rows in the sheet, except the ones that has a number that ends with 1 in column F. It just count all the rows, even the ones in column F that ends with 1.

How do I exclude those?

*edit* 
Some more information!

This is a sample of the data:
[image]

Could be up to 8000 rows some days. Column B always says "Independent instruction" so I'm using that as a base to count all the rows. Column F contain only numbers, or blank cells (meaning a number will be added later). I still want to count those rows as well (that's blank). It's just the rows that has a number in column F that ends with 1 that I want to exclude!

Comment: Note that the pattern "*" will exclude any cells in B:B that are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

`SUMPRODUCT` gives a bit more flexibility for criteria that involve more than straightforward string-matching:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN($B:$B)>0),--(RIGHT($F:$F,1)<>"1"))
```

Comment: Presumably you'd also need to check that F is not blank, but yes agree with the use of SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: It counts rows where F is blank, which sounds to me like the desired behaviour.

Comment: I'll leave it to OP to confirm, I was taking a guess.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! :)

Couldn't get it to work though! It asks if I'm trying to write a formula. And says it's not a formula. 

If I just type in the first part (with added sheet "SResult" forgot to add that):

    =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(SResult!$B:$B)>0))

It works and outputs the number 8432 which is right. 

Only using the later part:

    =SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(SResult!$F:$F,1)<>"1")) 

produces the same error. (Are you trying to write a forumla etc)

What might be wrong?

/Jens

Comment: I don't really understand the syntax here. And I can't find documentation anywhere.

This:

    =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(SResult!$F:$F)>200))

doesn't count all the cells that contain numbers larger than 200 for example. anyone that can help or provide links to some documentation?

Comment: Ok I got Excel to accept the formula. But I'm getting the #VALUE error. Does the formula work on your computer?

Comment: More progress. I narrowed the range down to B2:B33 and F2:F33 and the #VALUE error disappeared. Somehow $F:$F didn't work in the RIGHT function. It shows "0" though which isn't true since all the cells in column F says 200.  So it still doesn't work! This is the current formula =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(B2:B33)>0),--(RIGHT(F2:F33,1)<>"1"))

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a combination of SUM and IF. Remember to adjust the formula to match your Excel formatting, i.e. replace commas (,) with semicolon (;).

*This is an array formula (enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)*

```
=SUM(IF(MOD($F$2:$F$25,10)<>1,1,0))
```

Result (updated with your data set):

[image]

When pasting the image into merged cells, the error looks like that:

[image]

So you need to make sure the formula is pasted into a single (not merged) cell.

Array formula for values greater than 1000:

```
=SUM(IF((MOD($F$2:$F$25,10)<>1)*($F$2:$F$25>1000),1,0))
```

Array formula for values less than 1000:

```
=SUM(IF((MOD($F$2:$F$25,10)<>1)*($F$2:$F$25<1000),1,0))
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! :) I totally understand the logic in that, cool! It doesn't work though. When pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter it says (translated from Swedish) "Can't  assign a matrix formula over merged cells" Not sure if that's a correct translation. If I enter the formula with just enter it gives me 0 which isn't true!

Comment: By the way I had to delete the header since it contains text, else it showed an error. I updated the question by the way!

Comment: Hi @Jens, we're almost there! Correct, the header cannot be included, only numbers and blank cells. Also, I suspect the formula returns this error message because you are pasting it into merged cells (error on my side: "Array formulas are not valid in merged cells."). Make sure that the formula is pasted into a single cell - I'll update my answer with the new screenshot.

Comment: Well that's a problem... :) I work in a warehouse and the cell that shows the number of rows is on a big flat screen in the work area for all to see. It shows the number orders that's left to process. There's a lot of information on that screen and I have to keep that cell merged.  I did solve it by changing the formula so it outputs the number of cells that do end with 1 and put that cell in another sheet.  Then subtracting that cell from the main cell that counts the number of rows. Still I need to change it more though. Not sure if this is possible...

Comment: is it possible to output the number of cells in column F that doesn't end with 1 AND is greater than 1000? And the same thing but is smaller than 1000? Like in one cell you show the number of cells where the number is greater than 1000 and in another cell you show the ones that are smaller than 1000? These cells are not merged by the way. Sorry for being a pain!

Comment: @Jens you can "cheat" Excel a little bit and: step 1. enter your array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) into a single cell; then step 2. merge your cells (error message won't pop-up then). I'll think about your second requirement and come back to you with an update.

Answer (score 0):

The array formula:

```
{=COUNT(IF((F:F<>"")*(MOD(F:F;10)<>1);F:F))}
```

will count all non empty cells in the conditions of your question.

Don't forget to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to place the formula.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Got the same error as in Justynas answer: "Can't assign a matrix formula over merged cells"

Comment: You could always place the formula in another cells and link it afterwards to your merged cell...

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't this work?

Apart from the fact that you have transcribed it incorrectly (i.e. missing `=`, and smart quotes `”`) the 'F' condition in quotes is a Text value, a formatting issue  [@BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57088742/count-cells-that-doesnt-end-with-1#comment100700067_57088742) in connection with the 'B' values.

You say `It just count all the rows` so, syntactically corrected, your formula must be working on (a) all 'B's populated (with Text) and (b) all 'F's Numeric. As `1` and `"1"` are not the same, none of your entries in ColumnF will be excluded by your attempt (none end in `"1"`, though presumably some do end in `1`).

[@Pspl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579539/pspl)'s [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116045/1505120) works because its condition (for the 'F's) is based on MOD (applies to Number format values) and [@jsheeran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4742570/jsheeran)'s [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57089073/1505120) (my preference) because RIGHT is a string function that returns Text format even from a Number format value.

Put another way, with say `1` in F1,  `=F1="1"` returns FALSE (so `=F1<>"1"` and `=F1<>"*1"` return TRUE - that would not suit you) whereas `=RIGHT(F1)="1"` returns TRUE (or, to suit you, `RIGHT(F1)<>"1"` returns FALSE).